# How do I disconnect these wires?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

My ceiling fan stopped working and I want to remove the light box from the fan so that I can replace an in-line fuse holder.  In order to separate the light box from the fan rotation device, I need to unhook/disconnect/unsnap these wires from each other.  I don't know what these are called otherwise I would have performed some more thought out searches online.

Does anyone have any idea how to separate these wires?  It looks like there's a little snapping piece that locked them in, but before I start messing with it too much I thought I'd ask.  Help.

[image: Wire Connections]

Answer (score 5):

You should be able squeeze one of the connection heads and pull them apart. Some light kit also have a little tab on the side of the connector that have to be push in or pulled apart to release them.

Comment: After the breaker is off, of course...

Comment: Or the switch. but good call on that one.

Comment: Do the breaker. Sometimes the switch has been miswired and the neutral is switched. And I always confirm wires are not hot with a non-contact tester *even if* I have turned off the breaker.

Answer (score 1):

I used a pair of needle nose pliers to be able to squeeze the tab on both sides at the same time in order to pull the harness apart.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple answer.   Buy a combination wire-cutter/wire-stripper/terminal-crimper. Use the section of the tool that crimps non-insulated terminals. Use the 16-14 crimper --  place it right at the base of the section you want to squeeze, with the nipple just below the slots in the female plug. Squeeze and remove the male part. I had the tool and thought I'd try it, and it works amazingly well.

Answer (score -2):

I just grabbed both the small sides with pliers and pulled them apart.

Comment: You could have and might have permanently damaged the connectors by doing that.  Perhaps you don't care, and this might have achieved your goal but it's not a good answer to the question you asked. The other answer is correct ... you need to separate the tab by pushing in on it or squeezing the barrel.